# ```\mathcal``` and ```mathscr``` look the same in my template

Tags: mathcal

In my current template compiled by pdflatex, I am seeing `\mathcal` forced to `\mathscr`. For example, `$\mathcal{T},\mathscr{T}$` leads to the output[image]. Can anyone propose potential causes of this problem? P.S., this is what I believe to be a normal output from `\mathcal{T}`: [image]

Comment: Welcome! Let me guess: you have `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

Comment: @egreg Yes! Then what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no “normal” `\mathcal`. Different font sets make different choices about it.

You should be aware that `mathptmx` is essentially a kludge. The text font is (a variety of) Times, the symbols are drawn from here and there with the main purpose of making documents as small and possible when translated to Postscript or, in more recent years, to PDF.

It happens that `mathptmx` uses the RSFS font also loaded by `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` for its `\mathcal` alphabet.

There are better alternatives to `mathptmx` nowadays.

#### `mathptmx`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

Some text $A\cap B\in\mathscr{P}(X)\ne\mathcal{P}(X)$ and some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### `mathptmx` with `cmsy`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

Some text $A\cap B\in\mathscr{P}(X)\ne\mathcal{P}(X)$ and some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### `newtxtext,newtxmath`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Some text $A\cap B\in\mathscr{P}(X)\ne\mathcal{P}(X)$ and some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### `stix2`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

Some text $A\cap B\in\mathscr{P}(X)\ne\mathcal{P}(X)$ and some text

\end{document}
```

[image]